# Yii2 many to many doesn't return all relations

Tags: php, yii2

I have a many to many relationship of users to private leagues with a connecting table of `league_user`. However, when I use `$user->privateLeagues` it only returns the first relationship.

Here are my relationship definitions:

```
public function getLeagueUsers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(LeagueUser::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}

public function getPrivateLeagues()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PrivateLeague::className(), ['id' => 'league_id'])
        ->via('leagueUsers');
}
```

Example table data:

league_user

```
user_id league_id
1       1
1       2
```

private_leagues

```
id     name
1      first
2      second
```

Comment: looking to your data sample  you have only one rows  that match .. (league_id  = 1  --> id = 1)

Comment: What about league id 2 -> id 2?

Comment: Are the table names in the classes correct?  It should work. It is the same code as in the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerelationtrait.html#via()-detail)... Does $model->leagueUsers return 2 objects?

Comment: Yes, both are correct. $model->leagueUsers does return 2 objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading my Yii version fixed the problem.